# Telosys & Maven Modules - Code Generation Across Several Modules

Tags: java, maven, telosys

I have a Maven project with several submodules inside of it. They are packaged up so that I can reuse the code across several microservices. I can generate my Java classes in the parent project as I would like them to be, however, when I attempt to generate a class in a subdirectory my a package declaration that looks like:

`package ${target.javaPackageFromFolder(${SRC})};`

In a template will resolve to:

`package error.folder.not.started.with.the.given.src.folder.activities;`

In the `.java` class. This is understandable since my `$SRC` is at `src/main/java` and not `service-core/src/main/java`.

All of my modules are organized the same way, with `$SRC` at `src/main/java`, if I could just inform Telosys about the existence of these modules, I would be able to generate the code in the right place without needing to move it after generation.

I would just `init` Telosys in the `service-core` module, but I would also like to support generating DTOs in `dto-public` and controllers/tests in my `api-public`. Is there any way to support this in Telosys?

Things I've tried:

- Adding a parent `.vm` file that calls `$generator.generate` with a different directory. This configuration produces the above result.
- Changing the generated directory in the `templates.cfg` to include `service-core/${SRC}/${ROOT_PKG}/model/`. This configuration also produces the above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a multi-modules Maven project I recommend the following approach :

1. At **Telosys project level** define a specific global variable for each module in the file "**telosys.cfg**" and define the "root package" variable

Example:

```
# Root package (will be used as "root folder" in targets)
ROOT_PKG = org.demo.orders

# Maven project / parent  :
ProjectVariable.MODULE_PARENT = orders-parent

# Maven project / modules :
ProjectVariable.MODULE_MICROSERVICE   = orders-microservice
ProjectVariable.MODULE_DOMAIN         = orders-domain
ProjectVariable.MODULE_INFRA_MYBATIS  = orders-infra-mybatis
ProjectVariable.MODULE_INFRA_ELASTIC  = orders-infra-elastic
ProjectVariable.MODULE_INFRA_RABBITMQ = orders-infra-rabbitmq
```

You can keep the usual values for the standard variables:

```
SRC      = src/main/java
RES      = src/main/resources
WEB      = src/main/webapp
TEST_SRC = src/test/java
TEST_RES = src/test/resources
DOC      = doc
TMP      = tmp
```

2. At **Telosys templates level** (in each bundle) use the global variables to define the target folder in the file "**templates.cfg**"

You can combine $SRC, $MODULE_XXX and $ROOT_PKG to build the destination directory

Example (project modules initialization):

```
# "microservice" module
; pom.xml                    ; ${MODULE_MICROSERVICE}                     ; microservice/microservice-pom_xml.vm; 1 
; README.md                  ; ${MODULE_MICROSERVICE}                     ; microservice/README_md.vm ; 1 
; SpringBootApp.java         ; ${MODULE_MICROSERVICE}/${SRC}/${ROOT_PKG}  ; microservice/SpringBootApp_java.vm    ; 1 
; application.properties     ; ${MODULE_MICROSERVICE}/${RES}              ; microservice/application_properties.vm    ; 1 
; application-dev.properties ; ${MODULE_MICROSERVICE}/${RES}              ; microservice/application-dev_properties.vm; 1 

# Other modules initialization
; pom.xml ; ${MODULE_DOMAIN}        ; modules/domain-pom_xml.vm  ; 1 
; pom.xml ; ${MODULE_INFRA_MYBATIS} ; modules/infra-mybatis-pom_xml.vm   ; 1 
; pom.xml ; ${MODULE_INFRA_ELASTIC} ; modules/infra-elastic-pom_xml.vm   ; 1 
; pom.xml ; ${MODULE_INFRA_RABBITMQ}; modules/infra-rabbitmq-pom_xml.vm   ; 1 
; pom.xml ; ${MODULE_REST_APP}      ; modules/rest-app-pom_xml.vm   ; 1 
; pom.xml ; ${MODULE_REST_DTO}      ; modules/rest-dto-pom_xml.vm   ; 1
```

Other example (in the bundle for "domain" module):

```
pom.xml file    ; pom.xml      ; ${MODULE_DOMAIN} ; domain-pom_xml.vm      ; 1
readme file     ; README.md    ; ${MODULE_DOMAIN} ; domain-readme_md.vm    ; 1 

Entity        ; Entity.java                  ; ${MODULE_DOMAIN}/${SRC}/${ROOT_PKG}/domain/common ; domain-common/Entity_java.vm  ; 1 
AggregRoot    ; AggregateRoot.java           ; ${MODULE_DOMAIN}/${SRC}/${ROOT_PKG}/domain/common ; domain-common/AggregateRoot_java.vm  ; 1 
AggregRootRepo; AggregateRootRepository.java ; ${MODULE_DOMAIN}/${SRC}/${ROOT_PKG}/domain/common ; domain-common/AggregateRootRepository_java.vm  ; 1
```

3. With multiple source folders the Java package can be determined in 2 ways
   in **templates** (.vm files):

- using $target.javaPackageFromFolder() with the composite source folder,
  example:

> package ${target.javaPackageFromFolder("**${MODULE_DOMAIN}/${SRC}**")} ;

- using the ${ROOT_PKG} variable and adding the specific part of the package,
  example:

> package **${ROOT_PKG}**.my.sub.pkg ;

the ending part of the package name is not supposed to change, but if you want you can also use a global variable to define it. Example:

> package **${ROOT_PKG}**.**${DOMAIN_PKG}** ;

Comment: The issue is not with placing the `.java` files in the right locations, it's with how `package ${target.javaPackageFromFolder(${SRC})};` interacts with the folder location. This configuration still produces `package error.folder.not.started.with.the.given.src.folder;`

Comment: Yes, "target.javaPackageFromFolder()" interacts with the source folder location,  
 and the folder you pass to it is not the right folder.
So, you have 2 solutions  :
pass the rigth source folder :
**${target.javaPackageFromFolder("${MODULE_DOMAIN}/${SRC}")}**
or just use the "ROOT_PKG" + sub package : 
**${ROOT_PKG}.domain.model**

Comment: For clarity I added a 3rd part to my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may be looking for [$target](https://www.telosys.org/templates-doc/objects/target.html)

```
$target.javaPackageFromFolder(String srcFolder)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what produces `error.folder.not.started.with.the.given.src.folder.activities`

Comment: Aw dang, I don't think I can provide anything more valuable then.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution involves a `distribution.sh` script that copies out of the `src` folder to the appropriate destinations. This works fairly well as the packages that I'm writing to are unique across my modules. But if two of my modules have the same module, I'll be out of luck.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -rv src/main/java/my/company/model/* service-core/src/main/java/my/company/model
cp -rv src/main/java/my/company/dao/* service-core/src/main/java/my/company/dao
cp -rv src/main/java/my/company/service/* service-core/src/main/java/my/company/service
cp -rv src/main/java/my/company/dto/* dto-public/src/main/java/my/company/dto
cp -rv src/main/java/my/company/web/v6/* api-public/src/main/java/my/company/web/v6
cp -rv src/main/java/my/company/web/integration/v6/* common-test/src/main/java/my/company/web/integration
cp -rv src/test/java/my/company/web/integration/v6/* api-public/src/test/java/my/company/web/integration/v6
```